Why are the perturbations related by $\gamma'_{ab} = \gamma_{ab} - \mathcal{L}_v g_{ab}$?
Let $(M, g_{ab})$ be a spacetime manifold with a corresponding metric tensor field. If a one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $\phi_\lambda: M \mapsto M$ is given, then $(M, \phi^*_\lambda g_{ab}(\lambda))$ represents the same spacetime, following from the fact that each $\phi_\lambda$ is a diffeomorphism. Here, $\phi^*_\lambda$ pushes the metric forward in the usual sense, by pulling back its input vectors:
$$
(\phi^* g)_{ab} u^a v^b = g_{ab} (\phi_*u)^a (\phi_* v)^b
$$
In Wald's book on General Relativity, the following statement is given:

If, as in sections 4.4 and 7.5, we consider the first order
pertubation of $g_{ab} \vert_{\lambda = 0}$ obtained by
differentiating $g_{ab}(\lambda)$ with respect to $\lambda$ at
$\lambda = 0$, we find that $\gamma_{ab} = dg_{ab}/d\lambda \vert_{\lambda = 0}$ and
$\gamma_{ab}' = d(\phi_\lambda^*g_{ab})/d\lambda \vert_{\lambda = 0}$ represent the same physical
pertubation. But, it is not difficult to see that
$$ \gamma_{ab}' = \gamma_{ab} - \mathcal{L}_v g_{ab} $$ where $v^a$ is the vector field
which generates $\phi_\lambda$ and $g_{ab} = g_{ab}(\lambda = 0)$.

I tried deriving this, but fail to see how this is not difficult to see. The problem is that, when changing $\lambda$ in the expression $\phi^*_\lambda g_{ab}(\lambda)$, we are changing two things at once: both the metric itself, and the points on the manifold, which are remapped according to $\phi$. Either case, if we set $\lambda = 0$, we can use the definition of the Lie derivative to get:
$$
\mathcal{L}_v g_{ab} := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\phi_{-t}^*g_{ab}(\lambda = 0) - g_{ab}(\lambda = 0)}{t}
$$
where $v^a$ is the vector field generating $\phi_\lambda$. On the other hand, evaluating $\gamma_{ab}' - \gamma_{ab}$, we get:
$$
\gamma_{ab}' - \gamma_{ab} = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left( \phi_\lambda^* g_{ab}(\lambda) - g_{ab}(\lambda)\right)\vert_{\lambda = 0} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\phi_t^* g_{ab}(t) - g_{ab}(t) - \phi_0^* g_{ab}(0) + g_{ab}(0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\phi_t^* g_{ab}(t) - g_{ab}(t)}{t}
$$
assuming that $\phi_0$ is the identity map. This is almost the same as $-\mathcal{L}_v g_{ab}$, however, I cannot seem to understand how we can substitute $g_{ab}(t) \to g_{ab}(0)$. The difference between the expression, as suspected, comes from the fact that we have two things varying with $\lambda$ (the metric field itself and the points) when the definition of the Lie derivative only varies one thing (the points), and I can't seem to get around this problem. Does anyone know the missing piece that links the difference in perturbation fields with the Lie derivative? Any help whatsoever is appreciated.

$d(\phi^\lambda g(\lambda))/d\lambda|{\lambda=0} = d(\phi^\lambda g(0))/d\lambda|{\lambda=0} + d(\phi^*0 g(\lambda))/d\lambda|{\lambda=0}$, which is analogous to: if you have a function of $2$-variables $f(x,y)$ then $df(\lambda,\lambda)/d\lambda|{\lambda = 0} = df(\lambda,0)/d\lambda|{\lambda = 0} + df(0,\lambda)/d\lambda|_{\lambda = 0}$

@user8268 Thank you! I will look into this. I guess I should try to write out $\phi^*$ more explicitly to understand why it is analogous. I will try doing that once I get home!
